# How to find the overridden method in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, extends

When I am looking at a method in eclipse java, how do I jump to the method it overrides/extends?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Three ways to go about it.

#### Hyperlink Method (Mouse + Keyboard)

Press CTRL while hovering over the overriden method.

You should see an option called 'Open Super Implementation. Click it !

From **[here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/whatsNew/jdt_whatsnew.html)** :

[image]

#### Keyboard shortcut

And for bonus points, you can setup a Keyboard shortcut to do this like so :

[image]

When you try to setup a keyboard shortcut, you may filter by typing `Open Super Im`. On my Eclipse Indigo three matches were found. I tried setting them one by one until the shortcut appeared in `Navigate -> Open Super Implementation` like so :

[image]

#### Mouse only - Using the vertical Ruler

[image]

Click the ovverride marker that appears in the Vertical Ruler as in the above snapshot.

Comment: mille grazie, this is great!

Answer (score 10):

On the left edge of the editor there is a small triangle symbol next to the overwritten method. The tooltip tells you which superclass you are overwriting, clicking it leads you to the corresponding method.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

(Indigo Release) 
Put cursor on the method name and press CTRL+T to jump to the types list, from there you can jump to the super method. If you then click CTRL+T again it expands the supertype hierarchy.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me !! The quick type hierarchy only shows the sub-types and not the super-types !

Comment: I added, try ctrl+t again directly it should expand properly. This was for the Indigo release that I am using.