# Eclipse CDT override popup tooltip message won't go away even across other windows on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse

Ubuntu 18.04, Eclipse 2019.09, files:

cat.hpp

```
#include <string>

class Cat : public Animal {
    public:
        std::string noise();
};
```

animal.hpp

```
#include <string>

class Animal {
    public:
        virtual std::string noise() = 0;
        std::string poo();
};
```

[Example on a Git repo](https://github.com/cirosantilli/ide-test-projects/tree/f1b552faac648d387312593cdb408e92efd65e2c/cpp).

Now from the cat.hpp file, I want to go to the parent method declaration on Animal. So I click the triangle to the left of the line as shown at: [How to find the overridden method in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849631/how-to-find-the-overridden-method-in-eclipse/11849763#11849763)

However, if I move the mouse over the triangle quickly and click it, I do go to Animal, but the tooltip saying:

```
Implements Animal::noise via Animal
```

stays visible.

The hover has to be relatively quick, around less than 1 second, or else you can't reproduce. But this just happens to be the natural speed at which I would click it most of the time.

Even worse, it remains visible on top of other non Eclipse windows, e.g. the browser as I am writing this answer.

Is there any workaround for this, or an existing bug report that I can upvote?

There is this closed old bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=20987 but it was marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I just go to any one of those triangle symbols, and hover it without clicking for a second. The message then finally goes away.